# Problem with employing "well on the way"

Tags: meaning

Could you tell me either sentence might be correct ?

1. They are well on the way to reach success.
2. They reach success well on the way.

Comment: Actually, that should be *well on the way to **reaching** success.* The gerund functions as a noun, which you need because you can only be on your way ***to a place*** (or ***to*** some other NP). You can't be on your way ***to arrive*** somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

To be "well on the way" or "well on the way to" means to have made significant progress on a journey. The journey need not be a literal journey; it can be figurative:

**They are well on the way to success.**

**Success** there is perceived figuratively as the *destination* of a journey.

For that reason, we would not say "well on the way *to reach* success". The phrase "well on the way to" requires a noun-phrase complement; the complement must be of the same grammatical class as "destination".

So we could say:

**They are well on the way to *reaching* success**.

The word **reaching** is a nominal form of the verb.

When used of a literal journey:

**They departed two hours ago. They are *well on the way to* Boston.**